# Indexing by row name

Tags: python, indexing, jupyter-notebook, in-place

Can someone please help me with this. I want to call rows by name, so I used set_index on the 1st column in the dataframe to index the rows by name instead of using integers for indexing.

```
# Set 'Name' column as index on a Dataframe
df1 = df1.set_index("Name", inplace = True)
df1
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Then I run the following code:

```
result = df1.loc["ABC4"]
result
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

I don't usually run a second code that depends on the 1st before fixing the error, but originally I run them together in one Jupyter notebook cell. Now I see that the two code cells have problems.

Please let me know where I went wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should define your dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame("here's your dataframe")
df1.set_index("Name")
```

or just

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame("here's your dataframe").set_index("Name")
df1
```

Comment: Removing "inplace=True" solved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "df1" is not defined anywhere before doing something with it.
Try this:

```
# Set 'Name' column as index on a Dataframe
df1 = ''
df1 = df1.set_index("Name", inplace = True)
```

If its defined before, its value is NONE. So check this variable first.
The rest of the code "SHOULD" work afterwards.

Comment: Sadly, adding "inplace=True" didn't work at all. So when I deleted the "inplace" part, I got the result I wanted. But thanks for answering so quickly.